# Configuring "Web application URL" for team use

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

So, I'm trying to take advantage of 'Path Variables' (or Linked Resources), in my teams FlashBuilder4 project properties, so that its not such a bear to get a new project out of SVN, and up and running.  I'm all done with that, except that I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do for the "Web application URL" .

It doesn't allow me to create a "Path Variable" for http:// type items, only files and folders.

Short of saying that all developers need to configure their servers exactly *thus*, how can I configure this property so that individual team-members settings don't interfere with other team-members ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  What are path variables?  Where do you see them?  ARe you asking about some compile time argument?  Or does this refer to an IDE?  If an IDE, which one are you using?

Comment: IDE=FB4 (sorry about that)Window | Preferences | General | Workspace | Linked Resources .... this takes you to a list with the header "Defined path variables",

Comment: It seems like a strange setup to have each developer running their own local server, why not just have a server that is at a location that can be VPNed into or if you're all within an intranet just on a the LAN, then you have a common server that's used to "house" the service layer.  To debug Flex/Flash/web applications the client doesn't need to be running off a server the files can be run locally and so long as you add them to the flash player security you'll have no issues testing.

Comment: You put up two locations on the service server so one can be used by service layer developers for initial testing and the other can be used as a stable location for the front-end developers to build against the latest stable service-layer.  BTW understand this doesn't answer the question I'm just curious why you would go with this setup?

Comment: Sorry one more comment I took too long to edit, but if you've still got a week or so before you need to really get rolling on projects I'd suggest looking into maven to alleviate the pain of dealing with different environments. We use maven to avoid this being a bear it's been great after the learning curve (at least one person needs to go through this, can setup for all environments with a few XML files).  We now check in source and a pom and after checkout "mvn clean install" does a build "mvn flexmojos:flexbuilder" sets it up for import, can run mvn "cargo:start" to test the jar.

Comment: Hmm...I've heard about maven, but not really looked into it yet.  As to why we have that particular setup, its because this flex project is an addon to an old classic asp project (eventually subsuming the entire old project, I hope), and for development reasons there, each developer needs his own deployment configuration thats a close approximation to our live deployment.

Comment: In addition to that, when I've tried to debug our software without using the html server, and it has always failed (when interacting with our database, via weborb).  I've always figure it MIGHT be possible to configure it up to work, but haven't had the luxury of time to fine a solution to that, when I had a working alternative already, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem.  I hate it, but it gets me to where I need to go.

I assigned the "Web Application URL" to the value "https://HOSTS.DASHBOARD.DEV/foo/bar/blah/..."

Then, each of the developers needed, in addition, to create an entry in their HOSTS file, to resolve 'HOSTS.DASHBOARD.DEV' to the proper ip address.

This works (so far), even though I'm less than satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is create Linked Resources to point to a debug directory e.g. project/r11.1/dist in the main project. Everyone has *r11.1/dist* directory structure within their project. Each person has a local Apache server running, and each person sets up a local Alias in the server for r11.1 that points to whatever location the dist files are stored C:/.../r11.1/.

The SVN only contains the Apache Linked Resource name plus the common folder structure i.e. DISTRIBUTION/r11.1/dist along with the server name i.e. http://localhost.whatever.com/ + {DISTRIBUTION}/r11.1/dist

Does this make any sense in terms of what your after?